# add folder of .java files to intellij project

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm trying to add http://www.json.org/java/ to my java project as a module on IntelliJ. I cloned the source code from the git repo on this link, and I put the folder with all of the component .java files on my desktop.

When I try to add this as a module in Intellij, it allows me to, and the files show up but I cannot import them or do anything with them. Can someone shed some light on the proper procedure on how to attach these .java files to my project?

Comment: Why would you do that?  Wouldn't it be better to add that as a 3rd party JAR?

Answer (score 1):

Probably it is because the `.java` files are not recognized as source files but regarded as any file.

I suggest, you create a module in IntelliJ first, and move these files to the source directory of the new module.

1. Create a new module by clicking `File -> New -> Module -> Java`
2. Give it a name such as `json-java`
3. Clone from git repo directly into the new module's source folder. (`json-java/src` by default). IntelliJ should now recognize them properly as source files.

This should allow your java project to import the `.java` files.